# Directory listing error on published uploaded MVC3 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, visual-studio-2012

Ok so I uploaded an MVC3 application onto a server. The server is .net enabled. However when I go to the directory its under i am presented with this error:

**Directory Listing Denied
This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.**

I made sure that:

```
System.Web.Mvc

System.Web.Routing

System.Web.Abstractions
```

were set to copy local true.

I feel as if it may be because of two issues. Firstly it may be an IIS issue, which will require reading about virtual directory permissions.

or its because my project hasn't got what is effectively an index page. At the directory the layout is as follows.

- bin(folder)
- Content(folder)
- Models(folder)
- Scripts(folder)
- Views(folder)
- Global.asax
- packages.config
- Web.config

First MVC3 app Ive uploaded to a server, anyone know where im going wrong, or which one of the issues they think it is? If it is either of them?

Comment: What version of iis do you use?

Comment: Did you make sure the app pool the web site is running under is set to .Net 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll give you a check list that might help you out, or at least point you in the right direction.

1. Have you installed everything for **.Net** and **[MVC](http://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4211&ei=1Nc_UJuxPJSM9AS2toGwDA&usg=AFQjCNGdApZwZVNophXHoFXmeEb63cOCMg&sig2=Whyxj3ZgQE6DPZSLlbCk7g)** to work? MVC might work just [**deploying /bin folder**](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx). Installing the RTM MVC3 package will probably save you some IIS/Site configuration.
2. Run this, just in case... `aspnet_regiis -i`.
3. Target your brower to a know page from your project, for explame **/Home/Index**. Remember the MVC routing stuff, if you try something like "*http:/yoursite/views/controller/action*" you won't get the correct response. Now, if you get an error here, it will tell you something useful, like an Authorization error.

Answer (score 0):

Either add `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=”true”` in your `web.config` or apply [QFE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368) on your web server. More details in [How ASP.NET MVC Routing Works and its Impact on the Performance of Static Requests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx)